# Can I use existing inApp in iOs for the new version of the app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have submitted first version of my app and its inApps. Now I want to submit new version of the app using the existing inApps. But the app review team says that the inApp functionality is not implemented in your app. But I am using the same code before I submit with inAPPs also have implemented the inAPp functionality. Should I resubmit all the inAPPs that approved before with the new versions of the app?

Comment: Have you tested your updated app to make sure it actually works properly and supports the existing In App purchase items? That seems to be the problem. There is no need to resubmit existing IAP products just for an app update that supports those existing products.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to resubmit the IAPs.  Indicate in the submission form where the tester can purchase your IAPs.